# Matplotlib: y axis tick labels formatting with ScalarFormatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting

I want the common power indicator of the y axis tick labels to be x10^8 instead of 1e8 (the default matplotlib behavior). The following code accomplishes this quite nicely:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4.5))

plt.bar(0, 1.25e8, 1, color='b')
plt.bar(1, 0.32e8, 1, color='r')

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True))
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))

plt.savefig("./fig/test.png", dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

[image]

There are, however, two problems:

1) There is a noticeable gap after the decimal point. How could I get rid of it?

2) When I use the same script with slightly different data, the y axis labels sometimes show only one digit. Is there any way to fix the precision of the 
tick labels, even when it would only append zeros to every label? Unfortunately adding the line

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
```

doesn't work, as it overrides the ScalarFormatter line.